# Meaning of "auf Papier gebannt werden können"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From [DW - Hin und Weg](http://www.dw.de/hin-weg-das-reisemagazin-2014-12-13/e-18065378-9800):

> Kunstpädagogin Yasumin Sophia Lermer zeigt Interessierten bei einem Malkurs, wie Formen und Farben der Natur auf Papier **gebannt werden können**.

I would understand the sentence if it were

> ... wie Formen und Farben der Natur auf Papier bannen können

which would mean "how form and color of the nature can be captivating on the paper."

As it stands, however, "gebannt werden können" makes no sense to me. What does it mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression *„etwas auf etwas bannen“* is used in a figurative sense:

> *ein Geschehen auf die Leinwand/auf Zelluloid bannen*
>
> capture an event on canvas/film

Here, the expression is in the passive:

> *Sie zeigt, wie Formen und Farben der Natur auf Papier gebannt werden können.*
>
> She shows how shapes and colours of nature can be captured on paper.